# Lua - Love2d not responding?

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm building a simple shooting game on Love2d, everything seems smooth at first, but then after I add the check collision function, I tried to open the game but I got 'not responding' message. So I'm not sure what's the problem here.

I use the collision function taken from love2d forums. It keep giving message that "compare number with nil" and after I put on some game state conditions, it give me 'not responding' massage. Below is my code.

Main.lua

```
WIDTH = 480
HEIGHT = 800

Class = require 'Class'
require 'Player'
require 'Enemies'

PLAYER_SPEED = 150
BULLET_SPEED = 250

createEnemyTimerMax = 0.4
createEnemyTimer = createEnemyTimerMax

isAlive = true
score = 0

-- called when game starts 
-- load images, sounds of the game here
function love.load(arg)

    gamestate = 'play'

    background = love.graphics.newImage('gfx/milkyway.png')

    -- initialize player
    player = Player(200, 710)

    -- initialize bullet
    -- render image to map
    bulletimage = love.graphics.newImage('gfx/bullet.png')

    -- Entity storage
    bullets = {} -- array of current bullets being drawn and updated

    enemy = Enemies(math.random(10, 200), math.random(10, 200))

end

function love.update(dt)

    -- keypress for shooting
    love.keyboard.keysPressed = {}
    love.keyboard.keysReleased = {}

    -- move the player
    if love.keyboard.isDown('left', 'a') then
        if player.x > 0 then
            player.x = player.x - (PLAYER_SPEED * dt)
        end
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown('right', 'd') then
        if player.x < (love.graphics.getWidth() - player.img:getWidth()) then
            player.x = player.x + (PLAYER_SPEED * dt)
        end
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown('up', 'w') then
        if player.y > 0 then
            player.y = player.y - (PLAYER_SPEED * dt)
        end
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown('down', 's') then
        if player.y < (love.graphics.getHeight() - player.img:getHeight()) then
            player.y = player.y + (PLAYER_SPEED * dt)
        end
    end

    -- reset the game
    if gamestate == 'done' and love.keyboard.isDown('r') then
        gamestate = 'play'
        -- remove all the bullets and enemies from the screen
        bullets = {}
        enemies = {}
        -- reset timers
        createEnemyTimer = createEnemyTimerMax
        -- move player to default position
        player.x = 200
        player.y = 710
        -- reset gamestate
        score = 0
        isAlive = true
    end

    -- keep updating the positions of bullets when shooting
    for i, bullet in ipairs(bullets) do
        bullet.y = bullet.y - (BULLET_SPEED * dt)
        -- remove bullets when they pass off the screen
        if bullet.y < 0 then
            table.remove(bullets, i)
        end
    end

    Player:update()
    Enemies:update(dt)
end


-- global key pressed function
function love.keyboard.wasPressed(key)
    if (love.keyboard.keysPressed[key]) then
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end

-- global key released function
function love.keyboard.wasReleased(key)
    if (love.keyboard.keysReleased[key]) then
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end

-- called whenever a key is released
function love.keyreleased(key)
    love.keyboard.keysReleased[key] = true
end

-- called whenever a key is pressed
function love.keypressed(key)
    dt = love.timer.getDelta()
    -- to exit the game
    if love.keyboard.isDown('escape') then
        love.event.quit()
    end


    -- create bullets when shooting 
    if love.keyboard.isDown('space') then
        newBullet = {x = player.x + (player.img:getWidth() / 2), 
                     y = player.y, img = bulletimage}
        table.insert(bullets, newBullet)
    end

    love.keyboard.keysPressed[key] = true
end


function love.draw(dt)

    -- set background image
    love.graphics.clear(51/255, 43/255, 68/255, 1)
    drawBackground()

    -- draw player
    if gamestate == 'play' then 
        player:render()
    elseif gamestate == 'done' then
        love.graphics.print("Press 'R' to restart", WIDTH / 2 - 50, HEIGHT / 2 - 10)
    end

    love.graphics.setDefaultFilter('nearest', 'nearest')

    -- draw bullets
    for i, bullet in ipairs(bullets) do 
        love.graphics.draw(bulletimage, bullet.x, bullet.y, 3)
    end

    -- draw enemies
    enemy:render()

end

-- background is distributed for free on pixelstalk.net
function drawBackground()
    for i = 0, love.graphics.getWidth() / background:getWidth() do 
        for j = 0, love.graphics.getHeight() / background:getHeight() do
            love.graphics.draw(background, i * background:getWidth(), j * background:getHeight())
        end
    end
end
```

Enemies.lua

```
Enemies = Class{}

function Enemies:init(x, y)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

    enemies = {} -- array of current enemies on the screen

    -- render image to map
    self.enemyimg = love.graphics.newImage('gfx/enemy.png')

    self.width = self.enemyimg:getWidth()
    self.height = self.enemyimg:getHeight()
end

function Enemies:update(dt)
    createEnemyTimer = createEnemyTimer - (1 * dt)
    if createEnemyTimer < 0 then
        createEnemyTimer = createEnemyTimerMax

        -- create an enemy
        randomNumber = math.random(10, love.graphics.getWidth() - 10)
        newEnemy = { x = randomNumber, y = -10, img = self.enemyimg}
        table.insert(enemies, newEnemy)
    end

    -- keep updating the positions of enemies
    for i, enemy in ipairs(enemies) do
        enemy.y = enemy.y + (200 * dt)
        -- remove enemies when they pass off the screen
        if enemy.y > 850 then 
            table.remove(enemies, i)
        end
    end

    -- run our collision detection
    -- also we need to see if enemies hit our player
    while gamestate == 'play' do
        for i, enemy in ipairs(enemies) do
            for j, bullet in ipairs(bullets) do
                if CheckCollision(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height,
                    bullet.x, bullet.y, bullet.bulletimage:getWidth(), bullet.bulletimage:getHeight()) then
                    table.remove(bullets, j)
                    table.remove(enemies, i)
                    score = score + 1
                end
            end

            if CheckCollision(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height,
                            player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height)
            and isAlive == true then
                table.remove(enemies, i)
                isAlive = false
                gamestate = 'done'
            end
        end
    end
end

function Enemies:render()
    -- pixel aircrafts created by chabull and 
    -- distributed for free on OpenGameArt.org
    for i, enemy in ipairs(enemies) do
        love.graphics.draw(self.enemyimg, self.x, self.y)
    end
end

-- function to check collision
-- returns true if 2 objects overlap, false if they don't
-- x1, y1 are left-top coords of the first object, while w1, h1 are its width and height
-- x2, y2, w2, h2 are the same, but for the second object
function CheckCollision(x1, y1, w1, h1, x2, y2, w2, h2)
    if x1 < x2 + w2 and x2 < x1 + w1 and y1 < y2 + h2 and y2 < y1 + h1 then
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Love2d expert but Enemies.update is probably called every frame. Running a while loop with a condition `gamestate == 'play'` that most likely is true all the time in that function looks problematic to me.

You're basically trapped in an infinite loop instead of updating your game state.

Comment: Thank you, I've changed it to the if-then condition. It came back to the problem "compare nil with number". I think the issue here is that I have removed the bullet but check collision function still count it in. But I'm struggling to solve it.

Comment: well find out what is nil and why and avoid that situation